# EXCEPTION in dispatchHoverEvent for Accessibility

Tags: android, qt

Запустил приложение qt quick 1.1 на adnroid, при нажатии по форме(проект пустой) вылетает следующее исключение:

```
EXCEPTION in dispatchHoverEvent for Accessibility: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/dalvikvm( 7713): Stack overflow on call to interp (req=76 top=0xa02bd000 cur=0xa02b7324 size=24576 Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;.<init>)
I/dalvikvm( 7713): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;.<init>:VLLLLLI
I/dalvikvm( 7713):   method requires 32+20+4=56 bytes, fp is 0xa02b7310 (16 left)
I/dalvikvm( 7713):   expanding stack end (0xa02b7300 to 0xa02b7000)
D/dalvikvm( 7713): Method class init threw exception
I/dalvikvm( 7713): Shrank stack (to 0xa02b7300, curFrame is 0xa02b73f0)
W/Qt A11y ( 7713): EXCEPTION in dispatchHoverEvent for Accessibility: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Как это лечить? Заранее спасибо..

Comment: @Vadimcg, на сколько мне известно, поддержка OS Android значительно улучшена в Qt 5.2+, а так же в QtQuick 2.0. Попробуйте собрать проект под этой версией и посмотреть - может это простые проблемы совместимости.

Comment: Я использую Qt 5.2.1 .... Quick 2.0 не использую, потому, что на Android он вообще сразу вылетает...